# How to use CiviCRM for child Sponsorship?

Tags: civicontribute

I want to use CiviCRM for child sponsorship like the following:
The Idead: Create a charity website for orphans sponsorship that enables the contributor to select a child from a list of orphans then orphan profile will open with a Donate button.

What i have done inside Civicrm is:

- I created a group for orphans.
- I added the orphan children to the group.
- I created a public profile to list all orphans to the portal.
- I created a public profile to create a contributor record.
- I created a contribution page that use the contributor profile to collect contributor info like Name, address and email.
- I created a Sponsor Of relationship.

What i want to know is:

- How to add donate button to a child profile?
- How to create a dynamic relationship between the contributor and the orphan child throw the webform when the contributor clicks the donate button?

Comment: Essentially you want to be able to track contributions against each child for whom you are raising funds. Various approaches that come to mind that might offer a solution: utilising CiviCRM's Personal Campaign Pages and setting up one page per child. Or, if you are using Drupal as your CMS you could probably do something using a Civi-integrated webform and maybe the soft credit mechanism, so have a page per child with a donate button that takes the user to the webform and passes in a soft credit ID to link the payment to the child's contact record?

Comment: Graham, you might want to make this an answer.

Comment: is there any updates about the civicrm project. we are an orphan organization and we're thinking to use Civicrm for our system. we're looking for people with experience in this topic. looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: I expect your Answer will be removed shortly - until you get enough Reputation you can't comment - makes it tricky - but just so you know, we have a client using CiviCRM for sponsorship - you are welcome to contact me via Fuzion website and if i can share any advice from them I will happily do so.

Comment: See also: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/how-could-i-use-civicrm-for-sponsorship

Answer (score 2):

I like Graham's solution of using Personal Campaign Pages with one page per child.  However, that may not scale well; I don't know how many orphans you're working with.

I like Graham's idea of using Webform-CiviCRM on Drupal (or Caldera Forms integration on WordPress) to handle this.  I think creating a Relationship would be the easiest approach if you go this route rather than a soft credit.  I'm unsure whether you want to create the connection between the donor and orphan, or the donation and the orphan.

If neither of these options appeal to you, you can use a [Contact Reference custom field](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/#custom-fields) to help create the relationship.  However, if you want this to happen automatically, you would need to write an extension.  I recommend using the hook_civicrm_post hook.

Comment: Thank you Graham and @Jon-G for your support and i would like to mention that i am using drupal as CMS. 
I think the Personal Campaign Pages will not work with my model as i want to create an automatic relationship between the donor and the orphan child.
Also the proposed model will handle multiple orphanages and each orphanage will contains many orphans it is some how huge model and i think the  Webform-CiviCRM will help more and i have already tried it last week and it works in terms of creating the relationship but i want to make it easy for the donor to select child and donate for him

Comment: For example i want to do something like this [link](https://www.compassion.com/sponsor_a_child/default.htm)
Onepage to select the orphan and then donate for him.

Comment: Drupal Views could do the job of presenting a filterable/sortable listing of children, linking in to the webform.

Comment: @ahmed i'm building a similar project myself right now! Email me john@civifirst.com

Comment: @Graham i will try your suggestion and let you know soon

Comment: @Graham i have added a view to list all orphand as you recommended and it works fine also i created the webform as well, now how can i link them for example i want to add a button in the view called "Select ME" when the user clicks it it will go to the webform with the orphan details.
[See Hear](http://dev-kafel.pantheonsite.io/view1)

Comment: I Succeeded to add the "Choose Me" Button to the view using the custom field text in the view to display to orphan details, i will try the same with the webform as well.